# Does iText have ligature implementation for Indian languages such as Hindi, Marathi(india language)?

Tags: itext

**Does iText have ligature implementation for Indian languages 
such as Hindi, Marathi(india language)?**

Comment: Not yet. We've received plenty of attempts of code contributions, but none of them worked in a generic way. We've made it a project for 2014 (and it's priority depends on the demand by paying customers).

Comment: @BrunoLowagie thanks for reply.may i get my solution by using Apache FOP or PDFBox?

Comment: ????? Suppose you want to buy a car, would you go to a BMW dealer and ask them about a Peugeot or a Renault? I hope you understand from this analogy that you shouldn't expect an answer from me!

Comment: yes i can understand.but you may suggest me if possible.otherwise thanks and will wait for itext next version. :)

Comment: I don't know of any other product that supports what you need. Note that support for Hindi will not be in the next iText version, but in a version that is to appear somewhere in 2014. Could be July, could be December, but certainly not in January.