# Getting hindi to display on pdf created with JSP

Tags: java, jsp, pdf-generation

This is the code I have

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <%@ page trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true" %>
    <%@page import="com.itextpdf.text.Document"%>
    <%@page import="com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph"%> 
   <%@page import="com.itextpdf.text.PageSize"%>
   <%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.*,javax.servlet.*,com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException" %>
   <%@page import="java.io.*,java.text.SimpleDateFormat"%>
   <%@page import="java.sql.*,java.nio.charset.Charset"%>
   <%@ page import="com.itextpdf.tool.xml.ElementHandler,java.util.List,java.util.Arrays,java.util.Collections,java.util.*,com.itextpdf.text.pdf.*,com.itextpdf.tool.xml.ElementList,com.itextpdf.text.Rectangle,com.itextpdf.text.Element,com.itextpdf.text.*,com.itextpdf.text.Font,java.awt.Color,com.itextpdf.text.Font.FontFamily,java.util.Date,java.text.*,com.itextpdf.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<% 
String date=request.getParameter("user");
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
SimpleDateFormat myFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE,dd MMM yyyy");
final java.util.Date dtt = df.parse(date);
final String ds = myFormat.format(df.parse(date));

class HeaderAndFooter extends PdfPageEventHelper {
   private String name = "";
   protected Phrase footer;
   protected Phrase header;
   Font headerFont = new Font(FontFamily.COURIER, 13, Font.UNDERLINE);
   Font footerFont = new Font(FontFamily.HELVETICA, 11, Font.BOLD);
   String date1;
   public HeaderAndFooter(String name) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    header = new Phrase("***** Header *****");
    footer = new Phrase("**** Footer ****");
  }

  @Override
   public void onEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
     PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
     //header content
     String headerContent =name;
     //header content
     String footerContent = headerContent;
  //date selection
     ColumnText.showTextAligned(cb, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, new Phrase("Date:"+ds,headerFont), document.leftMargin() - 1, document.top() + 18, 0);
     }
  }
OutputStream output=response.getOutputStream();
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=details.pdf");
try{
    Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);
PdfWriter writer=PdfWriter.getInstance(document, output);
document.open();
writer.setPageEvent(new HeaderAndFooter(date));
XMLWorkerHelper worker = XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance();
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/yre", "root", "root");
Statement st=con.createStatement( ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
List arrlist = new ArrayList();
ResultSet rsta=st.executeQuery("Select * from yu where date='"+date+"' ");
int interval=0;
while(rsta.next()){
interval=rsta.getInt("inter");
}  
System.out.println(interval);
ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM ur_start2 where date='"+date+"' ");
 while(rs.next()){
 arrlist.add(rs.getString("data"));
 }  
for(int i=0;i<interval+1;i++){
  String str =(String) arrlist.get(i);
  worker.parseXHtml(writer, document, new StringReader("<html><head></head><body>"+str+"<br></br><br></br></body></html>"));
}
document.close();
writer.flush();
writer.close();
output.close();
}catch(IOException e){e.printStackTrace();} 
%>
</body>
</html>
```

This gives me only english characters in the displayed pdf.Whereas the hindi font is invisible.

What ever I have typed in hindi is also retrieved back in hindi on textareas.But on pdf I am not able to retrieve it in hindi.

What should I do to retrieve it in Hindi?

Comment: Are Hindi chars really invisible or appear as junk char sequence, boxes etc?

Comment: Can you log the hindi chars and see that do they really come up as you want or they appear as garbage characters ?

Comment: @PopoFibo invisible...no junk characters..in the database I get #2960.And when I retrieve on textbox,I get hindi text back.But when I pull it from database to pdf it doesnt come.

Comment: @SaifAsif I didnt get ur point?U mean in the textarea if they come in garbage?If yes,it comes properly on that...just on pdf nothing appears when I retireve from db

Answer (score 1):

In all possibility even the latest iText version does not support Devanagari script, reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18900933/does-itext-have-ligature-implementation-for-indian-languages-such-as-hindi-mara).

However, there are alternatives like using awt Graphics2D class, set a font supporting unicode chars and add it to the PDF (not as text though).

Example: [here](https://bitbucket.org/ivertex/itext-fork/src/079fcc1e0bfd7505a622f5bfc8896f130815a751/examples/src/in_action/chapter12/HindiExample.java?at=default)

**Output using the above reference:**

[image]

'New PDF in Hindi' is rendered as the text here

Comment: But in my case I need to print english and hindi both in one page.Will this work?

Comment: @user3040563 Yes try the example in the reference link, it displays the English chars as text and right below the Hindi graphics, see the edit above as well

Comment: I tried your example.not the graphics part but the first one `document.add(new Paragraph("Pure iText: " + str,
    new com.lowagie.text.Font(bf, 12)));`.I get this as output  `Konkani &#2361;&#2379; &#2360;&#2375;&#2360;&#2381;&#2360;&#2379;&#2344`

Comment: @user3040563 look at the code [here](http://codetidy.com/7732/); just replace `String text = "????";` with `String text = "भारत";`. Graphics part is important as that is the place where the Hindi chars are rendered, not before that.

Comment: @user3040563 the code in the link in my comment above would work as is and probably would give a better explanation of the intent

Comment: ok fine..I will try it out again...is there no way I could change some font xmlparser?

Comment: This I have on db '&#2361;&#2379' as characters.But when I use drawstring I get words overlapping...Ny idea y?

Answer (score 0):

Hindi script is not available in the core version of iText.
You could buy the addon pdfCalligraph of iText.

Or you could use the open source https://wkhtmltopdf.org/ that can handle HTML to PDF conversion and text scripts other then western.

There is also some paid API like https://pdftoolkitapi.com/ that do it all.