# Xmlworker displaying garbage/??? instead of hindi font

Tags: java, jsp, html-parsing, itext, xhtml2pdf

I have this code

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <%@ page trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true" %>
    <%@page import="com.itextpdf.text.Document"%>
    <%@page import="com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph"%> 
   <%@page import="com.itextpdf.text.PageSize,java.sql.Blob"%>
   <%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.*,javax.servlet.*,com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException" %>
   <%@page import="java.io.*,java.text.SimpleDateFormat"%>
   <%@page import="java.sql.*,java.nio.charset.Charset,com.itextpdf.text.pdf.BaseFont"%>
   <%@ page import="com.itextpdf.tool.xml.ElementHandler,java.util.List,java.util.Arrays,java.util.Collections,java.util.*,com.itextpdf.text.pdf.*,com.itextpdf.tool.xml.ElementList,com.itextpdf.text.Rectangle,com.itextpdf.text.Element,com.itextpdf.text.*,com.itextpdf.text.Font,java.awt.Color,com.itextpdf.text.Font.FontFamily,java.util.Date,java.text.*,com.itextpdf.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<% 
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
String date=request.getParameter("user");

OutputStream output=response.getOutputStream();
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=details.pdf");
try{
    Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 20, 20, 130, 20);
PdfWriter writer=PdfWriter.getInstance(document, output);
document.open();
BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont("c:/windows/fonts/arialuni.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
writer.setPageEvent(new HeaderAndFooter(date));
XMLWorkerHelper worker = XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance();
List arrlist = new ArrayList();
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gla", "root", "root");
Statement st=con.createStatement( ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM user_start2 where date='"+date+"' ");
 while(rs.next()){
 arrlist.add(rs.getString("data"));
 }
InputStream is=null;
 for(int i=0;i<interval+1;i++){
  String str =(String) arrlist.get(i);
StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer(); 
sb.append(str+"<br />");
String ss=sb.toString(); 
is = new ByteArrayInputStream(ss.getBytes());
  worker.parseXHtml(writer,document,is);
}
is.close();
writer.flush();
writer.close();
document.close();
}catch(IOException e){e.printStackTrace();}
output.close();
%>
</body>
</html>
```

The above code gives me this result
[image]

As you can see in the image,it displays english perfectly but for hindi font it displays ?????
I also tried adding character encoding with this line

```
is = new ByteArrayInputStream(ss.getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

But it gave me this output[image]

Previously I used only itext without xmlworker,and it gave me proper hindi fonts on the pdf,but since using xmlworker I am getting ???? or garbage values.

Let me know if I require to provide more data.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20966185/getting-hindi-to-display-on-pdf-created-with-jsp/20966668#20966668

Comment: Which method should I try?Coz i m not sure the graphics will work,since it will display html tags also.and the other method I have tried as u can see in the code given above

Comment: I'm unsure of what methods you are referring to, you can use alternatives like PdfBox or parse your html before rendering it

Comment: Look it up, alternative to iText [here](http://pdfbox.apache.org/)